# Ist "Sie zog ihn sich auf das Matratzenfloß" korrekt?

Tags: reflexive

Ich habe gerade den Satz "Sie zog ihn sich auf das Matratzenfloß" in einem Buch gelesen. Ich verzweifle mich, ob man hier "sich" wirklich braucht, weil das Akkusativ-Objekt "ihn" vorhanden ist. Soweit ich verstehe, die Meinung ist so wie "She pulled him on to the mattress raft". In dem Wörterbuch habe ich zu diesem Thema gar nicht gefunden.

Weil ich kein Muttersprachler bin, habe ich den englischen Satz mithilfe DeepL auf Deutsch übersetzt. Daraus habe ich den Satz ohne "sich" bekommen: "Sie zog ihn auf das Matratzenfloß". Jetzt habe ich zwei Fragen:

1. Braucht man tatsächlich "sich" in dem originalen Satz?
2. Wenn ja, gibt es einen Meinungsunterschied zwischen dem Satz ohne und mit "sich"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grammatikalisch ist das "sich" an dieser Stelle nicht unbedingt erforderlich, aber es gibt dem Satz eine zusätzliche Nuance in der Bedeutung. Und zwar bewirkt das "sich" den Eindruck des Besitzes, der Inbesitznahme oder der Aneignung. Man könnte sagen, die handelnde Person tut etwas *für sich*.

Ein guter Vergleich ist der Unterschied zwischen "nehmen" und "sich nehmen".

> Die Frau nimmt das Buch.

Hier wird nichts darüber gesagt, was danach mit dem Buch weiter passieren soll. Die Frau kann beispielsweise eine Verkäuferin in einem Buchladen sein, und das Buch anschließend einem Kunden geben. Oder die Frau nimmt das Buch für sich selbst, und legt sich damit für ein paar gemütliche Lesestunden auf das Sofa. Das bleibt bei diesem Satz vollständig offen.

> Die Frau nimmt sich das Buch.

Hier wiederum bekommt der Satz durch das zusätzliche "sich" ein Gefühl der Aneignung. Die Frau nimmt das Buch *für sich selbst*. Was genau sie mit dem Buch machen will, wird auch hier nicht gesagt, aber es geht eher um sie selbst, und wahrscheinlich nicht um jemanden anderen.

Ein anderes Beispiel wäre

> Er baut ein Regal (und verkauft es in einem Möbelladen).

im Vergleich zu

> Er baut sich ein Regal (und stellt seine eigenen Bücher hinein).

Im genannten Beispiel gibt das zusätzliche "sich" wie gesagt ein Gefühl der Aneignung. Die Person, die gezogen wird, ist klar passiv, und die Person, die zieht, ist der aktive Teil. Sie "nimmt sich" ihn (oder sie "nimmt ihn sich"), und er wird nicht wirklich gefragt.

Das "sich" in diesem Fall bewirkt eine Nuance, die vermutlich den meisten Muttersprachlern vertraut sein wird, die aber nicht einfach zu erklären ist. Das Zitat stammt übrigens vermutlich aus Uwe Timms "Die Entdeckung der Currywurst".

Comment: Interessant, danke! Und ja, ich habe den Satz in dem Buch "Die Entdeckung der Currywurst" von Uwe Timm gefunden.

Comment: Könntet man sagen, daß "sich" funktioniert als das englisches Wort "itself" in diesem Beispiel?

Comment: @BlauKakaPOW Nein, das passt in diesem Fall nicht. Eine etwas bessere Übersetzung, um diese Nuance auszudrücken, wäre vielleicht "for herself": "She pulled him onto the mattress float for herself". Aber das klingt in meinen Ohren auch ziemlich ungelenk. Ich bin nicht sicher, ob es im Englischen eine Möglichkeit gibt, diese Nuance gut auszudrücken.

Answer (score 2):

Ich stimme Hennings Antwort zu, möchte aber eine andere Formulierung anbieten:

*sich* ist hier gleichbedeutend mit *für sich*. Der Satz macht also eine Aussage zur Absicht der Frau. Sie zieht ihn **nicht** aus dem Wasser, um ihn vor dem Ertrinken zu retten, sondern für ihren eigenen Nutzen, beispielsweise um einen Gefährten zu haben.

Answer (score 0):

Die Frage »sich« oder nicht »sich« kann auch mit der Position der Ziehenden zu tun haben.

**Fall 1:** Sie steht im Wasser, vor ihr das Floß, er dahinter. Sie greift mit den Armen über das Floß und zieht ihn auf selbiges.

Aussage:

> Sie zog ihn auf das Matratzenfloß.

**Fall 2:** Sie befindet sich auf dem Floß und zieht ihn auf selbiges.

Aussage:

> Sie zog ihn [zu] sich auf das Matratzenfloß.

Vor der Aktion mag sie gedacht haben: »Den zieh' ich mir aufs Floß!«

Comment: Ich hatte auch zunächst überlegt, ob vielleicht einfach das "zu" fehlt. Aber dann müsste es meiner Meinung nach zwingend "zu sich ziehen" heißen, nur mit "sich" funktioniert diese Bedeutungsvariante nicht.